# Is it possible to pair iPhones to a specific bluetooth device or connect them to my Wi-Fi network via NFC tags?

Tags: bluetooth, iphone, ios, nfc

With the new capabilities of iOS 13's Shortcuts, I'm aware that events can be automated with NFC tags. However, can events be triggered by programming the tags for iPhones without having previously added such a shortcut? Such that anyone can come in and tap their phone to a tag to connect to my network?

Furthermore, can this be accomplished for pairing to a specific bluetooth device? I know this is possible with a shortcut, but I am wondering if it can be done on iPhones without any Shortcuts previously added.

If neither are possible, I could just create a QR code for the Wi-Fi connections, however I'm guessing you can't create a QR code to pair new devices to a bluetooth device.

Comment: I don’t see how this is possible with anything that requires authentication; like entering a pre-shared key for a WiFi network.

Comment: Even WPS (join network with a touch of a button) was abandoned because it was a massive security hole.

Comment: Actually, connecting to a Wi-Fi network, even with a key, can be automated for iPhone with a QR code, I made one for my apt.  And while pairing devices over bluetooth isn't supported for NFC automation in iOS 13, Airplay is.  There's a repo that documents QR functions [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents).